# Fluent NHibernate: How can I write this query as a criteria?

Tags: sql, fluent-nhibernate

The data structure is as follows:
A house has many rooms. Each room has many persons.

What I want to do is to get all persons for a house. In plain SQL I would write the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Room_id
IN
(SELECT Id FROM Room WHERE House_id = 1)
```

How can I write that in Fluent NHibernate'ish code?

For this example, we can assume that the entities and mappings look like this:

House entity

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual IEnumerable<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
```

House mapping

```
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.Name);
HasMany(x => x.Rooms);
```

Room entity

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual House House { get; set; }
public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

Room mapping

```
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.Name);
References(x => x.House);
HasMany(x => x.Persons);
```

Person entity

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
```

Person mapping

```
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.Name);
References(x => x.Room);
```

Comment: It's not a fluent issue - fluent is only for specifying mappings and configuration.  Depending on the version of NHibernate you are using you have a choice of HQL, Criteria API, or (if NH3) Linq.

Comment: Please, could you show your entities and mapping?

Comment: @Jakub: Done.
@UpTheCreek: Which solution will look the prettiest? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Awesome - which version of NHibernate are you using? Linq is by far the clearest method for this.

Comment: @Awesome - then I'd personally go with Linq when you have a standard query you need to write, and don't care exactly how the SQL will look. Jakub's ICriteria answer below is good though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get SQL query close to yours you can use these criterias:

```
var subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Room>(); // subquery
subCriteria.Add(Expression.Eq("House", house)); // where clause in subquery
subCriteria.SetProjection(Projections.Id()); // DetachedCriteria needs to have a projection, id of Room is projected here

var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Person>();
criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Room", subCriteria)); // in operator to search in detached criteria
var result = criteria.List<Person>();
```

This produces something like this:

```
SELECT this_.Id as Id4_0_, this_.Name as Name4_0_, this_.RoomId as RoomId4_0_
FROM [Person] this_
WHERE this_.RoomId in (SELECT this_0_.Id as y0_ FROM [Room] this_0_ WHERE this_0_.HouseId = @p0)',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

I tested it in FNH1.2 and NH3.1 but it should work well in NH2.1 as well.

EDIT:
UpTheCreek is right. Linq is more clear than Criteria API. For example:

```
var query = session.Query<Person>().Where(x => x.Room.House == house);
var linqResult = query.ToList<Person>();
```

which produces different SQL query but result set is the same:

```
select person0_.Id as Id4_, person0_.Name as Name4_, person0_.Room_id as Room3_4_
from [Person] person0_, [Room] room1_
where person0_.Room_id=room1_.Id and room1_.House_id=2
```

Comment: I am glad it helps. But UpTheCreek is right. Linq is more clear than criteria API which I personally hate:). On the other 

side I am cautious about NH Linq because of historical reasons - Linq implementation in NH2.1 was not very usable. But judge 

for yourself (Edited post).